# Dynamics CRM: Is it possible to add fields to the Connection Roles entity?

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-2016

I added the Connection Roles entity to my solution but there is no button to create a new field. Is it not possible? I need to be able to add a "Weight" to Connection Roles. I need the ability to have reports that are sorted by the Connection Role "weight".

For example, I would assign a weight value of 1 to the Connection Role of CEO, 2 to VP, 3 to Director, etc. Then when I pull the report I can sort by that field, so that the contacts display in order of seniority. Thanks.

Comment: Don't think you can do this, what about putting the fields on the contact entity and then using that in the report? Or make a custom entity? I think your options are pretty limited here.

Comment: You can't add such custom field. I think that one option that you can take into consideration would be simply prepending your Role name with the "weight", so your roles would be "1 - CEO", "2 - VP" etc. Not very nice, but should do the job.

Answer (score 1):

The **Connection Role** entity is not customizable; it is not even possible to create custom relationships with it.

Adding the entity to a solution serves no purpose. In fact every solution already has a Connection Role node by default and all that is customizable can be done there.

Connection Roles are used in the **Connection** entity, which in fact *is* customizable. An option could be to add a custom weight field there.

Comment: The downside of putting it on the Connection entity is that you then has to set the Weight for every single connection (100s), vs on the Connection Roles which I'd only have to set about 10. I could possibly build a workflow to set the Weight field on the Connection though,.

Comment: @BillyGreen: I agree, it would not be the ideal solution, but it may do the job.